Range of OLS regression coefficient when combining disjoint datasets
How would you approach the following problem?
We have two disjoint datasets, $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$. We can separate them into $\mathbf{X}_1 (A\times 1)$, $\mathbf{X}_2 (B\times 1)$ and $\mathbf{Y}_1$, $\mathbf{Y}_2$, such that $\mathbf{X}_1$ concatenated with $\mathbf{X}_2$ is equal to $\mathbf{X}$ (and similarly for $\mathbf{Y}$). $\\$

Given the coefficients $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$, what are the range and best guess of the coefficient $\beta$?
What if we run the regressions with intercept?

Additionally, consider the same question under the assumption that the $(x, y)$ pairs are drawn independently and identically distributed (i.i.d.) from a zero-mean 2D Gaussian distribution.
My Approach:
I started by using the following properties:

$\mathbf{X}^\prime\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{X}_1^\prime\mathbf{X}_1 + \mathbf{X}_2^\prime\mathbf{X}_2$

$\mathbf{X}^\prime\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{X}_1^\prime\mathbf{Y}_1 + \mathbf{X}_2^\prime\mathbf{Y}_2$

$\beta_1 = (\mathbf{X}_1^\prime\mathbf{X}_1)^{-1}(\mathbf{X}_1^\prime\mathbf{Y}_1)$

$\beta_2 = (\mathbf{X}_2^\prime\mathbf{X}_2)^{-1}(\mathbf{X}_2^\prime\mathbf{Y}_2)$


Based on these, I derived: $\beta = (\mathbf{X}_1^\prime\mathbf{X}_1 + \mathbf{X}_2^\prime\mathbf{X}_2)^{-1}(\mathbf{X}_1^\prime\mathbf{Y}_1 + \mathbf{X}_2^\prime\mathbf{Y}_2)$
However, I'm unsure how to proceed from here.

I could understand what you want to achieve but the problem statement is not accurate enough (the biggest problem is that you confused "parameter" and "estimate of parameter"), so let me first restate the problem as follows:

Suppose you have two datasets (in matrix form) $\mathcal{D}_1 = (Y_1, X_1)$ and $\mathcal{D}_2 = (Y_2, X_2)$, where $Y_i \in \mathbb{R}^{n_i}$, $X_i \in \mathbb{R}^{n_i \times p}$. After fitting $\mathcal{D}_i$ to the linear model $E[Y|X = x] = x^\top \beta$, the OLS estimate is $\hat{\beta}_i = (X_i^\top X_i)^{-1}X_i^\top Y_i$, $i = 1, 2$. Is it possible to express the OLS estimate $\hat{\beta}$ of $\beta$ when fitting the data $\mathcal{D} = \left(\begin{bmatrix} Y_1 \\ Y_2 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}X_1 \\ X_2\end{bmatrix}\right)$ to the same linear model in terms of $\hat{\beta}_1$ and $\hat{\beta}_2$?

As you have shown,
\begin{align*}
\hat{\beta} = \left(\begin{bmatrix}X_1^\top & X_2^\top\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}X_1 \\ X_2\end{bmatrix}\right)^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}X_1^\top & X_2^\top\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} Y_1 \\ Y_2 \end{bmatrix} = (X_1^\top X_1 + X_2^\top X_2)^{-1}(X_1^\top Y_1 + X_2^\top Y_2).
\end{align*}
In general this is the best you can get (unless there are special structures of $(Y_i, X_i)$, e.g., when $Y_1 = Y_2$ and $X_1 = X_2)$.  You may use the Woodburry matrix identity $(A + B)^{-1} = A^{-1} - (A + AB^{-1}A)^{-1}$ to get one $\hat{\beta}_i$ reappear in the expression of $\hat{\beta}$, but this actually looks less concise than the original expression.
Now let's treat some special cases (which are the three cases of your interest).
Case 1: $p = 1$ (intercept-free simple linear regression)
In this case, the model is $E[Y|X = x] = \beta x$. The OLS estimates of $\beta$ based on $\mathcal{D}_1, \mathcal{D}_2$ and $\mathcal{D}$ are respectively
\begin{align*}
& \hat{\beta}_1 = \frac{x_1^\top y_1}{x_1^\top x_1}, \tag{1}\label{1} \\
& \hat{\beta}_2 = \frac{x_2^\top y_2}{x_2^\top x_2}, \tag{2}\label{2} \\
& \hat{\beta} = \frac{x_1^\top y_1 + x_2^\top y_2}{x_1^\top x_1 + x_2^\top x_2}. \tag{3}\label{3}
\end{align*}
By $\eqref{1}$ and $\eqref{2}$, we have $x_i^\top y_i = \hat{\beta}_ix_i^\top x_i$, $i = 1, 2$.  Substituting them into $\eqref{3}$ yields
\begin{align*}
\hat{\beta} = \frac{\hat{\beta}_1 \|x_1\|^2 + \hat{\beta}_2 \|x_2\|^2}{\|x_1\|^2 + \|x_2\|^2}. \tag{4}\label{4}
\end{align*}
It can be seen from $\eqref{4}$ that $\hat{\beta}$ is a weighted average of $\hat{\beta}_1$ and $\hat{\beta}_2$: $\hat{\beta} = w_1\hat{\beta}_1 + w_2\hat{\beta}_2$,
where $w_i = \frac{\|x_i\|^2}{\|x_1\|^2 + \|x_2\|^2}$, $i = 1, 2$.  If your goal is to give a bound of $\hat{\beta}$ in terms of $\hat{\beta}_i$, an easy one  is then
\begin{align*}
|\hat{\beta}| \leq w_1|\hat{\beta}_1| + w_2|\hat{\beta}_2| \leq \max(|\hat{\beta}_1|, |\hat{\beta}_2|). 
\end{align*}
Case 2: $p = 2$ (standard simple linear regression)
In this case, the model is $E[Y|X = x] = \alpha + \beta x$. The OLS estimates of $\beta$ based on $\mathcal{D}_1, \mathcal{D}_2$ and $\mathcal{D}$ are respectively
\begin{align*}
& \hat{\beta}_1 = \frac{x_1^\top y_1 - n_1\bar{x}_1\bar{y}_1}{x_1^\top x_1 - n_1\bar{x}_1^2}, \tag{5}\label{5} \\
& \hat{\beta}_2 = \frac{x_2^\top y_2 - n_2\bar{x}_2\bar{y}_2}{x_2^\top x_2 - n_2\bar{x}_2^2}, \tag{6}\label{6} \\
& \hat{\beta} = \frac{x^\top y - n\bar{x}\bar{y}}{x^\top x - n\bar{x}^2}. \tag{7}\label{7}
\end{align*}
Similar substitution as in Case 1 gives that
\begin{align*}
\hat{\beta} = \frac{n_1\hat{\beta}_1(x_1^\top x_1 - n_1\bar{x}_1^2) + n_2\hat{\beta}_2(x_2^\top x_2 - n_2\bar{x}_2^2) - n_1n_2(\bar{x}_1\bar{y}_2 - \bar{x}_2\bar{y}_1)}{x^\top x - n\bar{x}^2}. \tag{8}\label{8}
\end{align*}
Unlike $\eqref{4}$, $\eqref{8}$ cannot be expressed as a weighted average of $\hat{\beta}_1$ and $\hat{\beta}_2$ (due to the effect of mean terms).  Hence a bound depending only on $\hat{\beta}_i$ seems hard to obtain.
Case 3: $(X, Y)$ are drawn from bivariate zero-mean 2-D Gaussian
This is identical to Case 1, because the normality assumption guarantees the conditional mean of $Y$ given $X = x$ must be $E[Y|X = x] = \beta x$ for some $\beta$ (without intercept because of the zero-mean assumption).

Zhanxiong: There was a similar question here along with an answer ( arshdeep ) that I wasn't able to follow. More information is given than in the current question so that could be the difference but I didn't follow how he obtained $x^{\prime} y$ in his expression. Maybe it's not correct ? Thanks for any insights. https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/78881/how-to-obtain-bivariate-regression-coefficients-from-two-univariate-regression-c/78882#78882

@mlofton Sadly, arshdeep is incorrect.

Can't I also say the following in general case?
$(X_1^TX_1 + X_2^TX_2)^{-1} (X_1^TY_1) > \beta_1$  because $X_2^TX_2$ is positive definite?

I want  to find a range of $\beta$ using $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$, not necessarily a precise answer.

@mo1965 See my edited answer.

Thanks! Didn't word that part correctly. It's a two-part question - first without that assumption and the second without that assumption.
So, to summarize:
When there is no assumption: $\$

$\beta = ((X1^T X1)^{(-1)} + (X2^T X2)^(-1))^{(-1)} (\beta_1 + \beta_2)\$

( got this after Woodbury matrix identity). So, we can say that it's equal to the weighted average of betas. (still figuring out the range here)
$\$
And when there is the assumption - as you noted above
$$\beta = \frac{|X_1|^2 \beta_1 + |X_2|^2 \beta_2}{|X_1|^2 + |X_2|^2}$$
$$|\beta| <= max (|\beta_1|, |\beta_2|)$$

@mo1965 Please take a little more time on proofreading and formatting! No rush :)

Rewrote the question. Hope this is better and thanks for pointing that out.

@mo1965 Thank you for editing. Is your $X$ at most of two columns?

yep, it's just one column. It's a one variable regression. Added that to the question too

@mo1965 I further edited my answer based on your updates.

@whuber: thanks for that wisdom. that's probably a good thing because I was unable to get his claims to wotk out. and I tried hard. all the best.

The regression coefficient in the combined dataset could be anything.
In this set of scatterplots showing three possibilities, the two parts are shown with different colors.  This is an extreme case where one part has a correlation coefficient near 1 and the other part has a correlation coefficient near -1.  The panel headings give the correlation coefficients of the combined dataset, which are determined by how the two parts are separated.  I hope no further explanation is needed!


Thanks for the reply, however, this is not really what I am looking for. This shows me that the beta can be anything, which i agree with, but it can be shown as a function dependent on $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ values.

I appreciate the clarification, but for the record, that's not what you had asked.
