Can I utilize Ridge Regression to update coefficients of a Linear Regression model for a new dataset?
I have fitted a Linear Regression Model using one dataset. Now, I have another smaller dataset that I want to refine the model with. Can I use Ridge regression to update the estimated coefficients for this new dataset? Or do you recommend a more appropriate approach?
Edit: after the useful Answer by John Madden, I have implemented his approach using Python, as follows, do you find any issue in this code in reflecting that logic:
# Step 1: Compute coefficients on dataset (X1, y1)
beta1 = np.linalg.pinv(X1) @ y1
print("Original coefficients:", beta1)

# Step 2: Compute residuals on dataset (X2, y2)
y_hat2 = X2 @ beta1
residual2 = y2 - y_hat2

# Step 3: Perform ridge regression on residuals
ridge_reg = Ridge(alpha=alpha)
ridge_reg.fit(X2, residual2)
delta = ridge_reg.coef_

# Step 4: Adjust coefficients
beta2 = beta1 + delta
print("Adjusted coefficients:", beta2)


Do you mean that you want to know what the regression on both data sets combined would have been if you calculated on all data when you had the chance?

I want to update the coefficient  of the first linear regression model using the dataset2

What do you mean by "update" the coefficients?

Using the coefficients from the first model as the start point of the second regression

But what does that mean? Both OLS and ridge regression have closed-form solutions. You don't need a starting point like you do in deep learning. You just calculate. $//$ Perhaps give some additional context to what you're doing. In particular, what are you doing, and why are you doing it?

ok, simply I am trying to do a simple parameter-based transfer learning for regression.  I want to utilizes the information gained in model1 and adjust it using data2

If all you have available are the estimated coefficients, you're out of luck: that's not enough information.  You need the equivalent of the sums of squares and products matrices (as well as the data counts).  For details please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23481/ and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/533857 (for the ordinary regression case).  Your question--without the irrelevant appeal to ridge regression--is asked and answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/644458.

@whuber the transfer case is different from the "online" case; transfer learning in statistical models is blowing up in the stats literature rn, there are some cool recent articles it's worth checking out. <Li 2022 JRSS B https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.10593> is a good entrypoint to this literature.

@AdhamEnaya looks good, small change: "np.linalg.pinv(X1) @ y1" is better expressed as "np.linalg.lstsq(X1,y1)[0]". Also, make sure to center/scale X/y before step 1 (as always when doing regularized regression).

@John The question does not refer to "transfer" explicitly: it uses the phrase "refine the model with."

I think that what you mean is that you have some coefficients estimated from a first dataset $(\mathbf{X}_1,\mathbf{y}_1)$ denoted as $\hat{\beta}_1$. Then, for dataset $(\mathbf{X}_2, \mathbf{y}_2)$, you want to do something like ridge regression, but instead of penalizing the $\ell_2$ norm of $\hat\beta_2$, you want to penalize the deviation between $\hat\beta_2$ and $\hat\beta_1$.
Or mathematically,
$$
\underset{\beta}{\min} \Vert \mathbf{y}_2-\mathbf{X}_2\beta\Vert_2^2 + \lambda\Vert\beta-\hat\beta_1\Vert_2^2 \, .
$$
If that's right, you can accomplish this by noting that:
$$
\underset{\beta}{\min} \Vert \mathbf{y}_2-\mathbf{X}_2\beta\Vert_2^2 + \lambda\Vert\beta-\hat\beta_1\Vert_2^2 
\iff
\underset{\delta}{\min} \Vert \mathbf{y}_2-\mathbf{X}_2(\hat\beta_1+\delta)\Vert_2^2 + \lambda\Vert\delta\Vert_2^2 \\
\iff
\underset{\delta}{\min} \Vert (\mathbf{y}_2-\mathbf{X}_2\hat\beta_1) -\mathbf{X}_2\delta)\Vert_2^2 + \lambda\Vert\delta\Vert_2^2 
$$
This suggests the following procedure:

Compute an estimate of $\hat\beta_1$ on the dataset $(\mathbf{X}_1,\mathbf{y}_1)$ using a procedure of your choice.
Compute the residuals using the coefficients learnt from $(\mathbf{X}_1,\mathbf{y}_1)$ as $\tilde{\mathbf{y}}_2 = \mathbf{y}_2 - \mathbf{X}_2\hat\beta_1$.
Do a standard ridge regression on $\tilde{\mathbf{y}}_2$ against $\mathbf{X}_2$ to get deviation coefficients $\delta$.
Set $\hat\beta_2 = \hat\beta_1 + \delta$.

For the properties of such a procedure in the context of Lasso rather than Ridge regression, see <Li 2022>.
Regrettably, I don't know of the analysis for the Ridge regression case.

thanks, a lot. I think this your solution is similar to this one:
https://adapt-python.github.io/adapt/generated/adapt.parameter_based.RegularTransferLR.html#adapt-parameter-based-regulartransferlr

@AdhamEnaya yes looks similar.

thanks. I have implemented your logic in python could you please have a look.

I have a follow-up question, please. my regression process is GLM-based, it is clear what I have to do in steps 1 and 2 of your proposed procedure, but I am not very sure about step 3, should I use the normal ridge regression, or a 'regulatized' version of my GLM model?

@AdhamEnaya good question. Ideally, we would use a regularized version of your GLM. But the hard part is that the residuals from dataset 2 may no longer follow the appropriate distribution for your GLM. This paper discusses the situation https://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.14328.pdf, but I think implementing it will require writing custom GLM code that allows for nonstandard regularization.
